How to turn off Sanoid's snapshotting for a subtree of datasets?
I'd like to set up Sanoid to create snapshots of my system dataset, except for the Docker images under /var/lib/docker. I have the following two templates:
[template_system]
        frequently = 0
        hourly = 0
        daily = 5
        monthly = 3
        yearly = 0
        autosnap = yes
        autoprune = yes
        
[template_ignore]
        autoprune = no
        autosnap = no
        monitor = no
        frequently = 0
        hourly = 0
        daily = 0
        monthly = 0
        yearly = 0

AFAIU, ignore shouldn't create any snapshots.
I am then using these two templates in the following way:
[builtin/ROOT]
        use_template = system
        recursive = yes

[builtin/ROOT/ubuntu/var/lib/docker]
        process_children_only = yes
        use_template = ignore
        recursive = yes 

However, with these settings, I am still seeing snapshots getting generated for builtin/ROOT/ubuntu/var/lib/docker, e.g.:
builtin/ROOT/ubuntu/var/lib/docker/8882d709e8d82bb317bb5b33065e0de6f0cdcc9dab4f6513eb0ac811a3893b47@591379486
builtin/ROOT/ubuntu/var/lib/docker/8882d709e8d82bb317bb5b33065e0de6f0cdcc9dab4f6513eb0ac811a3893b47@autosnap_2024-04-23_10:54:36_daily
builtin/ROOT/ubuntu/var/lib/docker/8882d709e8d82bb317bb5b33065e0de6f0cdcc9dab4f6513eb0ac811a3893b47@autosnap_2024-04-24_04:17:46_daily
builtin/ROOT/ubuntu/var/lib/docker/8882d709e8d82bb317bb5b33065e0de6f0cdcc9dab4f6513eb0ac811a3893b47@autosnap_2024-04-25_01:50:31_daily
builtin/ROOT/ubuntu/var/lib/docker/8882d709e8d82bb317bb5b33065e0de6f0cdcc9dab4f6513eb0ac811a3893b47@autosnap_2024-04-26_04:33:42_daily
builtin/ROOT/ubuntu/var/lib/docker/8882d709e8d82bb317bb5b33065e0de6f0cdcc9dab4f6513eb0ac811a3893b47@autosnap_2024-04-28_09:52:35_daily
builtin/ROOT/ubuntu/var/lib/docker/8882d709e8d82bb317bb5b33065e0de6f0cdcc9dab4f6513eb0ac811a3893b47@autosnap_2024-04-28_10:15:00_monthly

For comparison, for system datasets I have the same snapshots created, and also monthly ones:
builtin/ROOT/ubuntu/var/lib@autosnap_2024-04-14_14:01:03_monthly
builtin/ROOT/ubuntu/var/lib@autosnap_2024-04-23_10:54:36_daily
builtin/ROOT/ubuntu/var/lib@autosnap_2024-04-24_04:17:46_daily
builtin/ROOT/ubuntu/var/lib@autosnap_2024-04-25_01:50:31_daily
builtin/ROOT/ubuntu/var/lib@autosnap_2024-04-26_04:33:42_daily
builtin/ROOT/ubuntu/var/lib@autosnap_2024-04-28_09:52:35_daily

So it seems ignore's monthly and system's daily settings are applied to datasets under builtin/ROOT/ubuntu/var/lib/docker, which is of course not what I want. I would like Sanoid to create neither daily nor monthly snapshots for those datasets. How do I achieve that?

The obvious, if inelegant, solution would be to move your docker filesystem outside of its existing parent, say to builtin/docker/var/lib or something.  There might be a nicer spot, but without seeing your ZFS structure it's hard to speculate.  Another long shot that might be worth a try is to reverse your filesystem declarations in the Sanoid config.  It might be a "first-one-wins" type of thing, so putting the docker filesystem first, then the recursive parent definition might make a difference.  Or might not.  Dunno.

FWIW, this issue seems related to https://github.com/jimsalterjrs/sanoid/issues/627, but there's not a lot of meat there, other than to suggest it should be possible. Perhaps as they suggest, try with the --debug flag?
